# First match from json stream using jq

Tags: json, command-line-interface, jq

why is `first(select(.updated_at=="2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"))` returning more than 1 result when input is

```
{"_id":"a","updated_at":"2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"}
{"_id":"b","updated_at":"2019-06-03T19:27:15.192Z"}
{"_id":"c","updated_at":"2019-06-03T20:02:11.538Z"}
{"_id":"d","updated_at":"2019-06-03T21:12:05.764Z"}
{"_id":"e","updated_at":"2019-06-04T07:55:04.251Z"}
{"_id":"f","updated_at":"2019-06-03T22:21:37.276Z"}
{"_id":"g","updated_at":"2019-06-03T20:57:42.296Z"}
{"_id":"h","updated_at":"2019-06-03T18:56:07.687Z"}
{"_id":"i","updated_at":"2019-06-04T09:28:08.276Z"}
{"_id":"j","updated_at":"2019-06-04T08:54:05.048Z"}
{"_id":"k","updated_at":"2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"}
{"_id":"l","updated_at":"2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/2sm1pKQ2fS

I also tried using `nth` but it doesn't seem to have the expected behaviour either:

https://jqplay.org/s/DeSANQZtj7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, `first`'s input is a stream of objects and thus it is run once for each one. To run it once for entire stream specify `-n/--null-input` flag on the command line and access inputs using the `inputs` function. This way `first`'s input will be `null` and its argument will be a stream of objects `select`ed from `inputs`, so it will be able to yield only the first one.

```json
$ jq -n 'first(inputs | select(.updated_at == "2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"))' file
{
  "_id": "a",
  "updated_at": "2019-06-03T16:36:53.194Z"
}
```

Comment: Interestingly, it works for me just fine but only as long as I have just one condition inside select. As soon as I add another one with `and`, it no longer stops after the first result.

Comment: @synek317 If you send a jqplay link demonstrating the problem I can take a look

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce it... I work with huge jsonl files and it seems it depends on which fields I check. The command I run is

`js -nc 'first(inputs | select(.prop1 == "PROP1" and .prop2 == "PROP2"))' large.json`

Depending on the .prop1 and .prop2, sometimes I get the output immediately and sometimes jq outputs the result and then keeps running for some time. All tested properties are just strings.

Comment: @synek317 Interesting. I know `first` is buggy, but can't reproduce this behavior. Anyway, `select([.prop1, .prop2] == ["PROP1", "PROP2"])` might be worth a try...